# Another "bully overflow"

Tags: discussion, answers, citing-sources, faq-content

Yeah I know downvote downvote downvotes. But rep doesn't count here.

Far from the Jewish spirit of welcoming in new people, guests, etc. you are bullying people with your downvote tactics.

Where is the FAQ? Where does it say all my answer must have a rabbinic source?

Who says there are black and white, wrong and right answers to certain questions? Downvotes should be for blatantly wrong answers, like someone saying pork is kosher or that Jesus really is the Messiah..

People are starting to hate Stack Overflow but it's a useful site to get information when you have a technical problem.

You don't have many posters and you're not doing yourselves any favours to get them.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: About citing sources in answers -- you might want to see http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1444/answers-when-is-a-source-required and http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/712/better-to-post-an-answer-with-no-source-or-not-to-post-at-all

Comment: Is this a plural "you" or do you have someone specific in mind and are refraining from mentioning them by name?

Comment: Also related: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/144/5323

Answer (score 4):

People's votes are their own. That is the official StackExchange position. Explaining downvotes is [encouraged but not required](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/why-do-you-cast-downvotes-on-answers?rq=1). See also [Why do you cast downvotes on answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/why-do-you-cast-downvotes-on-answers?rq=1)

It's not true that we're not welcoming. We are in fact much more welcoming than other SE sites - Stack Overflow for example.

There is no official rule that answers must include sources, however, because people on the internet are anonymous (you're not *really* a cow, right?), we can't just take your word for things. Read: [Answers - When is a source required?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1444/answers-when-is-a-source-required) and [Better to post an answer with no source, or not to post at all?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/712/better-to-post-an-answer-with-no-source-or-not-to-post-at-all)

Downvotes are for whatever someone feels is incorrect, not an answer/question, badly written, etc. It's not personal against you. Just being not blatantly incorrect doesn't make it good. As someone with 20k on SO, you should be familiar with this kind of thing already.

I actually think that we're doing well obtaining new users - there are almost always a few new ones per day.

---

No one is forcing you to use Mi Yodeya. If you don't like the community, you can: a) try to like it, b) deal with it, or c) just quietly disappear.

Comment: I recommend making reference to http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1444/answers-when-is-a-source-required in your third paragraph.

Comment: I recommend having a link to your FAQ on the main page of the site rather than refer to a question in meta

Comment: @CashCow [This is linked](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1734/can-i-consult-mi-yodeya-as-i-would-a-rabbi) from the [tour](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Yes I have 20K on SO because the questions there are technical ones, with right and wrong answers, and I am able to use my expertise to give right ones.

Much that StackExchange tries to avoid "opinion based" answers or questions that lead to them, that is likely to be the case on questions asked on this site. On some matters all agree, on others there are different opinions..

Comment: @CashCow Yet, those are official opinions, backed up by recognized sources. Opinions like "what's your favorite Chanukah song" are still off topic.

Comment: And there are many subjective questions when it comes to biblical events, especially in B'reshit.

Comment: @CashCow Name me some.

Comment: Sarah's laugh in Vayeira. For which I got 2 downvotes for my answer.

Comment: @CashCow I wouldn't call that subjective. It's asking for reasons for the laughing and the following conversation. One answer provided a recognized source's response; one provided their personal opinion.

Comment: Yeah may as well leave this site then. Would have been a nice discussion forum if people were allowed to give own opinions. I can't be bothered going around finding sources and posting them. The questioner can do it themselves. I hope you have lots of rabbis with nothing better to do than scan this site.

Comment: @CashCow Well, we'll be sorry to see you leave. But SE is *not* a forum - it's a structured Q&A with defined rules.

Comment: @CashCow, as Scimonster indicated in this answer, voting is not [necessarily] an expression of official policy, but one of the voter's opinion of the post. The more persuasive a post is, the more likely it is to get voted up and not down. Citing relevant sources is a really good way to make an answer persuasive. Another is clear, well-written  reasoning. Everyone's entitled to their own opinions, but if you want others to express approval for yours, I recommend that you give them as much reason as you can to do so. This is a matter of basic human communication. q/1444 (above) is commentary.

Comment: @CashCow I think the misunderstanding here is in what the point of this site is.  It is _not_ a "discussion forum" as you seem to have understood.  It is not a blog.  It is for asking questions and receiving answers to those questions, with clearly defined guidelines to keep the site functioning and _not_ becoming a discussion forum.  This is clearly stated in our [Tour](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) which hopefully every new user reads.

Comment: Firstly it isn't obvious that Tour means FAQ plus it is hidden away in the footer where nobody can see it and then it doesn't say unsourced or self-opinionated answers should not be given or they will get downvoted.

Comment: And.yeah disappear is what I may well do. If this were a shul you wouldn't be getting my membership with this attitude towards me. I put in another well-sourced answer, got almost positive feedback in a comment then yet again a -1 rating.

Comment: @CashCow The tour isn't 'hidden away' - it's actually quite visible *before* you log in.

Comment: I get logged in automatically.

Comment: I'm being stalked on mi yodeah